# Facebook question migrated to Webapps in error?

Tags: discussion, migrated-questions

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19520/what-is-liked-and-where-that-is-liked was migrated from Stack Overflow to Web Applications.  While the title is pretty bad, and suggests that Web Applications is the proper venue for it, the actual question suggests the user is trying to integrate Facebook like buttons into his website.

> Example: My web site displays a list of different car makes, and the user clicks 'Like' to one of those car makes. . . .How do I do that? That is, which attributes do I need to specify in the iframe tag? Can I use the iframe tag at all?

It sounds more a Stack Overflow type of question, given that he is building his own site. In fact, the references to the "iframe" tag seem to have something to do with [this bit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) of the Facebook API documentation.

Perhaps his question is in need of some editing and un-migrating, or perhaps it should have been closed as a duplicate. It seems a fairly basic question, so I tried to find a duplicate, but I didn't find one that quite covered the same ground.

Comment: I notice that Web apps has closed the question as off topic, so whatever else, it seems it should not be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you've hit on the problem here with these phrases: "the title is pretty bad" and "the actual question suggests".

It wasn't at all clear what the user was asking. While the question may have been migrated in error (I had a discussion with the SO mod about it and a 2nd Web Apps mod closed the question), we weren't convinced that it was a suitable question for Stack Overflow in the first place.

Perhaps it should have been handled by adding comments asking the user to clarify and simple closure as "not a real question".

Comment: Sounds reasonable, so no action to take then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'll step up to the plate and say it was me that migrated that question.

The reason I migrated it was because it was about configuring a link. Is that programming? I'm not sure it is. Is it about extending Facebook as an *application* into your website, I thought it was.

I am happy to be proved I got the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: I don't know if I'd consider it programming, but it does seem to be a Facebook API question, which I think are on topic.  I think it's definitely off topic for webapps, which is only for end users of web applications, not people trying to decipher the Facebook developer documentation.

Comment: Let's call it a draw and migrate to Webmasters